# Install shield 2016 - Change Display Icon

Tags: installshield

How to change **Display Icon** in "Add or Remove Program" using ISwi object in Install shield using vb script.

Comment: please share your code, what you've done.

Comment: Sorry Praveen, I don't have one.
My simple Requirement is Display icon Should appear in  "General Information-->Add or remove Programs-->Display Icon" what ever i write in my script.

Answer (score 0):

**InstallShield 2012 automation object**:

With the [ISWiProject Automation Object](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm) you are able to change a lot of internals of an InstallShield project. For "Add or remove programs" section you may change CompanyName, CompanyPhone, CompanyURL, but not the ProductIcon.

Let's look what is [ProductIcon property](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912527-Set-the-icon-displayed-in-Add-Remove-Programs). This is the path to your local resource (usually path to an .ico file somewhere under the resources of your project). If so, just copy new icon, you would like to see, into this location (overwrite existing icon) and after use automation to re-built the project. During build it's gonna use icon from this location which you just override. Here you go, you just replaced your icon.

**InstallShield 2015 automation object**:

If you have ability to use latest automation object, you in luck to set requested properties through your scripting. The new [ISWiProject Object (Advanced UI and Suite/Advanced UI)](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/ISWiProject-Ste.htm) allow you to set *ArpIcon* and *ArpIconIndex* as path to .exe, .ico or .dll files and index of the icon to be used. Those would be the properties you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Slava.
I've already changed CompanyName, CompanyPhone, CompanyURL . These are easy to do But My requirement is put the path for the user thorugh script for Display Icon and later let him build it.

Comment: I have modified my answer and added comments for new automation object. Sorry, didn't read carefully title, you are using InstallShield 2016.